# Chrome custom tabs - android - User Agent

Tags: php, android, http-headers, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm seeking a way to change the User_Agent Var when you use the Chrome Custom Tabs that send to the server of the web page.

Or if there is a way to send a custom global var to recive it in php like $_SERVER[''].

IMPORTANT 1: NOT VIA URL.

IMPORTANT 2: Using Android Studio (gradle).